# How to stay connected to a private WiFi LAN in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking

I'm trying to do some network programming with a WiFi device (a raspberry Pi) which exposes a WiFi access point, but does not provide general internet access, except for forwarding DNS requests to 8.8.8.8.

I can connect to this AP under Linux, no problem.
Under Windows 10, it briefly connects (I can ping 8.8.8.8), but it quickly decides there is no internet access and disable the WiFi.

(I have disabled the window automatic reconnect setting for other WiFi APs)

How can I keep Windows 10 connected to this WiFi LAN?

Similar question here - no answers:
[How to keep Windows 10 connected to wifi without internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/1650052/how-to-keep-windows-10-connected-to-wifi-without-internet)

Comment: I never experienced WLAN disconnecting or being because of a missing internet connection. And that wouldn't make any sense either. I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Check the comments in your link, they come to the same conclution