# Notebook WiFi switches routers when ISP Internet drops

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

How do I get my notebook to stop disconnecting from a router just because there is no Internet access?

I have multiple (WiFi) routers in my house (plus a couple of extenders). On my notebook (Lenovo Yoga 7i - Windows 11 Home) I have my development router set to "Connect Automatically"; I do NOT have this option checked for the main house router (or any of the extenders). I do occasionally (manually) connect to the main house router to access the printer.

When I am connected to the development network, and my Internet access drops (because my ISP stinks), the notebook will disconnect from the router and connect to the main network. Of course, there is no Internet there either (at the time, because my ISP stinks). So it seems to keep trying to switch between the two routers looking for the Internet.

When I am doing development, mostly I don't care about the Internet being available. I would much prefer that the connection to the development router remain active whether there is Internet access or not. If I have a need to access the Internet, I will deal with it. I can NOT access my development server from the main router, so this disconnect interferes with my development.

This is not a problem with DHCP or IP addressing. The Development router hands out 192.168.4.* while the main router uses 192.168.1.*. The setup (probably not the best approach) works fine as long as the ISP keeps my Internet up.

Comment: Use:   netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid="WiFi Network Name" networktype=infrastructure   to hide access points you do not want to access.

Comment: As stated, I do occasionally _want_ to connect to the main router (manually). Will this prevent it from showing in the list of available networks?

Comment: Do not hide routers you wish to access, so if you wish to access 2 routers, you will probably have to connect as necessary.

Comment: @DavidAM do the answers in https://superuser.com/questions/1650052/how-to-keep-windows-10-connected-to-wifi-without-internet help you? Basically stopping Windows from probing or detecting that the internet is down

Comment: @YisroelTech That looks helpful. I have added the Registry Value to activate the "NoActiveProbe" Policy. We will see if that solves the (intermittent) problem.

Comment: @YisroelTech - The registry entry noted in the answer to that question - (https://superuser.com/a/1719303/1724863) - seems to have solved the problem. If you want to convert your comment, I will accept it as the answer.