Windows 10/11: Disable reset of network adapter on loss of connectivity
When losing online connectivity Windows 10 & 11 seem to reset the network adapter to try to heal that situation. I can reproduce it in our firewall test environment:
I block the world and my Windows machine resets network adapters or connections so I always lose all SSH connections, too.
Is there a way to stop Windows 10 & 11 from doing that, from resetting the adapter and just live with that situation?

Is this about Wi-Fi or about Ethernet? Because as far as Wi-Fi is concerned, I have observed that Windows does disconnect from the network (not reset the adapter), even though no other network is available.

@DanielB Oh, good question. Nearly all of the time I connect to the Wifi in our test env. But I just got a bit further and the concerning component is called NCSI. I remember, I heard of it. It checks connectivity, proxies, captive portals etc. What I do not understand is why it drops the connection - yes - even if there are no other Wifi connections available. Everything is ok with NCSI, except these diconnects. If someone knows where to set actions or how to set it up so it does not disconnect anymore. It can do whatever it wants, but not disconnect. I believe this is what I am looking for.

I found those links:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-disconnect-from-wifi-if-internet/7a3db93d-a77d-49a1-a607-353c7867cec0
and
https://superuser.com/questions/1650052/how-to-keep-windows-10-connected-to-wifi-without-internet
(there are even more)
But they all sems to result in NCSI not working correctly anymore. I just tried "the second one" from the community answer. But that results in a "not connected" icon - even if I'm connected.
Disconnecting Wifi when there are not other (preferred) networks does not make any sense.
